# change a variable in a for loop from 0 to 2, and back again to 0

Tags: python

Hi I am looking for a smart way to get a for loop in Python in which one variable, say k, has to shift from 0 to 2 and than back to 0 up to the end of the loop. Something like

```
k = 0
for j in range(15):
    fancycode
    k = k + 1
```

In which for each loop k has the following values

```
loop1 k = 0
loop2 k = 1
loop3 k = 2
loop4 k = 0
loop5 k = 1
loop6 k = 2
loop7 k = 0
...
```

I may use an if statement but I would like to know whether there could be something smart that does not burden my code

Comment: Would `k = j % 3` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do it is to use [itertools.cycle()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=chain#itertools.cycle) For example:

```
import itertools

my_cycle = itertools.cycle(range(3))
for j in range(15):
  k = my_cycle.next()
```

valid in Python 2.x

for 3.x you should use

```
import itertools

my_cycle = itertools.cycle(range(3))
for j in range(15):
  k = next(my_cycle)
```

This will work with any iterable regardless of it's nature.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

for index, value in enumerate(islice(cycle([0, 2]), 15)):
    print('loop{} k = {}'.format(index, value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using modulo! (%)

```
for j in range(15):
    fancycode
    k = j % 3
    print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

using list comprehension you can:

```
for j, k in ((j, j % 3) for j in range(15)):
    print('j: {0}, k: {1}'.format(j, k))
```

will print:

```
j: 0, k: 0
j: 1, k: 1
j: 2, k: 2
j: 3, k: 0
j: 4, k: 1
j: 5, k: 2
j: 6, k: 0
j: 7, k: 1
j: 8, k: 2
j: 9, k: 0
j: 10, k: 1
j: 11, k: 2
j: 12, k: 0
j: 13, k: 1
j: 14, k: 2
```